# Daphne Django file upload size limitations

Tags: python, django, docker, daphne

I am using Daphne for both socket and http connections. I am running 4 worker containers and running everything locally right now in a docker container.

My daphne server fails if I try to upload a file that is 400MB. It works fine for small files upto 15MB.

My docker container quits with error code 137. I dont get any error in daphne logs. The daphne container just dies but the worker containers keep on running.

Does anyone know if there is a way to increase upload limits on daphne or I am missing something else?

I start the daphne server by 
`daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 project.asgi:channel_layer --access-log=${LOGS}/daphne.access.log`

Comment: Nothing being logged by Daphne suggests that it might be running out of memory...

Comment: that is what I was suspecting too. Is there a way to fix this, I am using `docker-compose up` to run my containers. I have looked around and seen `oom-kill-disable` flag to pass into docker run. But I am not able to run using that.

Comment: I don't know enough about docker to say - if memory is the issue then you're going to have to find some way to increase what is available.

Comment: @solarissmoke you were right in the sense that Docker was running out of memory. Once I allocated more memory everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

This is because daphne loads the entire HTTP POST request body completely and immediately before transferring control to the django with channels.

All your 400 MB are loaded into RAM [here](https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/67cfa98b0016abee66fe1d90c7db3ea1ea1d001f/daphne/http_protocol.py#L188). Your docker container died due to the [out of memory](https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137) reason.

This happens even before checking for the size of the request body in django. See [here](https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/253)

There is the open ticket [here](https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/126)
If you want to prevent it right now use a [uvicorn](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn) instead daphne. Uvicorn must pass control to Django with chunks. And depending on the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` django setting you will receive a temporary file on your hard disk (not in RAM). But you need to write your own `AsyncHttpConsumer` or `AsgiHandler` because `AsgiHandler` and `AsgiRequest` from channels do not support chunked body too. This will be possible after the [PR](https://github.com/django/channels/pull/1251).