# Django Daphne large file uploads

Tags: python, django, upload, out-of-memory, daphne

I have a Django web application that uses Channels and Daphne for websocket communication. All of my websocket stuff is working properly without any issues.

My trouble comes from the fact that my server also allows me to upload files to the server. Small files (even up to 282mb) are being uploaded and working fine with no issues.

However large files are resulting in a `500 Internal error - Daphne` and showing this stack trace:

```
2018-10-29 12:40:14,009 - ERROR - http_protocol - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\http_protocol.py", line 176, in process
    "body": self.content.read(),
MemoryError
```

I'm guessing this is telling me that Daphne is running out of memory. I found reference here: [Daphne Django file upload size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986220/daphne-django-file-upload-size-limitations) which also helps to confirm this finding.

What I need an answer for is how to solve it. I am not running my project inside of Docker, I am on a Linux VM instance. If I increase the total RAM in use on the entire VM will daphne be able to grab some more?

Is there some way I can specify to daphne that it is allowed to use more memory than it is current? This server instance has 4gb of RAM and my file is only 675mb so unless it is storing multiple copies in memory at once it should have enough to fit this file as is.

How can I enable Daphne to be able to successfully accept large file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55237320/5717886).

Daphne redundantly and prematurely loads the entire HTTP POST request body into RAM. If you need to upload large enough files - you need to use [uvicorn](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn) instead daphne.

Replace `daphne -p <your-port> -b <your-host> ...` with `uvicorn --port <your-port> --host <your-host> ...`

After that you have to write your own `AsyncHttpConsumer` because `AsgiHandler` and `AsgiRequest` from channeles do not support chunked body too.